# Diff between 2 files (awk)

Tags: linux, awk, diff

I tried a number of solutions from Stack Overflow, but without a favourable result.
I have 2 files and want to remove the entries from `file1` that are mentioned in `file2`.

File1

```
1,email1@domain.com,9
9,email9@domain.com,1
8,email8@domain.com,6
2,email2@domain.com,1
15,email15@domain.com,3
6,email6@domain.com,1
```

File2

```
email1414@domain.com
email9@domain.com
email15@domain.com
email1919@domain.com
```

Result

```
1,email1@domain.com,9
8,email8@domain.com,6
2,email2@domain.com,1
6,email6@domain.com,1
```

Could you help me please?
My failed attempt:

```
awk -F',' 'NR==FNR{c[$1]++;next};c[$2] > 0' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following awks and let me know if this helps you.

***Solution 1st:***

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} ($2 in a){next} 1' File2 FS="," File1
```

***Solution 2nd:***

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} !($2 in a)' File2 FS="," File1
```

Comment: Either of these is the right answer (`awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} !($2 in a)' File2 File1` being the obvious/common/idiomatic one). If they don't work for you then you probably have control-Ms in your input file so use `dox2unix` or similar to remove them.

Comment: If you don't have dos2unix utility then try commands (tr -d '\r' < Input_file > temp_Input_file && mv temp_Input_file Input_file).

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thank you very much for this solution , it's work perfectly , i think it's the best answer .

Answer (score 3):

<s>since</s> if there is no chance of false positives, this might be the easiest

```
$ grep -vf file2 file1      

1,email1@domain.com,9   
8,email8@domain.com,6 
2,email2@domain.com,1 
6,email6@domain.com,1
```

a better idea is to change to fixed strings (instead of pattern matching)

```
$ grep -vfF file2 file1
```

Comment: An outrageously improbable scenario: one of the domains in `file2` is `example.ac` (Saint Helena, Ascension, Tristan de Cunha), and one of the domains in `file1` is `example.ac.uk` — false match.  That said, it is incredibly improbable as a problem.

Comment: Thank you @Karakfa for ur quick reply , but  unfortunately it prints all lines :(

Comment: Probably `-vxFf`, as you need fixed strings, not patterns, and considering what Jonathan Leffler wrote.

Comment: @Anouar - it prints what is in the example. I checked it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you for this important not , on my case i have all domain are "gmail.com" .

Comment: @user31264 Really ? i tried it on centos , won't work , it prints all the content on file1 , but i will try on ubuntu

Comment: @user31264 you are right , it works on ubuntu, kali and all Deb dist, but not on centos fedora , Centos always read the first file , if i put firstly file1 it read file1 if file2 same thing . i think that's a problem of compatibility on REDHAT distribution.

Comment: @Anouar that would be outrageous, unthinkable breakage for any grep, I'm sorry but I just don't believe it. How can a tool decide to pick one of your file names and always open that file first no matter where it occurs in a list of arguments?

Comment: @karakfa That would fail with a false match if `bar@gmail.com` was in file2 and `foobar@gmail.com` was in file1.

Comment: @EdMorton your question you can test it , and about your last example you are right

Answer (score 1):

Here is my awk file which does this:

```
FNR==1 {NFILE++}

NFILE==1 {a[++n]=$0}

NFILE==2 {b[$0]}

END {for (i=1; i<=n; i++) if (!(a[i] in b)) print(a[i])}
```

It prints all lines of file1 which are NOT in file2, as per your example.

Comment: Tahnk you , but plz when should I put filename ?

Comment: @Anouar awk -f prog.awk file1 file2

Comment: Thx , still not working , i try to add separator same thing , i use centos 6.9 with awk version 4.0.2 / i will switch to an other dist to try my chance

Comment: @Anouar - try ubuntu, or install gawk.

Comment: It works with ubuntu and debian . I think it is a bug on centos .

Comment: This **can't** work since it's not isolating the 2nd field from file1. Even if that was fixed this would be very over-complicated and inefficient for the task at hand. Also, don't use all upper case variable names to avoid clashing with builtin variable names (and obfuscating your code by making it look like you're using builtin variables when you aren't).

Comment: @EdMorton about "this can't work" - I wrote "It prints all lines of file1 which are NOT in file2".  It does exactly this.  As for upper case varuable names, NFILE should be a builtin, but there is no such builtin, so I intentiaonally use it with upper case.  And no, it is not over-complicated, it is long enough to be clear, rather than concize and cryptic, like obfuscated awk code.

Comment: @EdMorton Also the "beautiful" answer `awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} !($2 in a)' File2 FS="," File1` doesn't work if the FILE2 is empty.  Empty files confuse the popular `FNR==NR` idiom.

Comment: `NFILE` is the builtin `ARGIND` (in gawk). Yes, the solution is for the case the OP has where the files are not empty. Your solution will fail for the other case the OP probably doesn't have where `file1` is too big to fit in memory - that's another case not worth worrying about until/unless the OP tells us she has it. There is nothing obfuscated about [the right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45272788/1745001) - it's simply idiomatic and if you're going to use a tool/language you should learn and use it's idioms.

Comment: EVERY solution will fail if one of the files is too big in memory, so this is lousy claim.  After I say that the common idiom fails in some cases you write that I "should learn and use it's idioms"?  Do you read *your own* comments?

Comment: @user31264 sorry , it works with centos now , the problem was on file2 i write it on windows so the difference between LF and CR create this problem.